# Android ImageView layout alignment

Tags: android, imageview, alignment

How can change my layout to make image 1 more like image 2? I don't mind if it's the text that moves up or the image that moves up.

[image: What I have]

[image: What I need]

my layout file is like so :-

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/imp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/stats_chr" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="AA" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to set Gravity to your `LinearLayout` and `ImageView` both `android:layout_gravity="top"`

Comment: Dungeon crawling cat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Use `android:gravity="top"` for `LinearLayout` or `android:layout_gravity="top"` for `ImageView`

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/imp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer does not works for me. Here is my solution

Add android:scaleType="fitStart" to the ImageView.

Comment: Yes this worked me & accepted answer did't worked me too.